# Adding /Putting share buttons of facebook,twitter in your iphone application?

Tags: iphone

Have anyone worked with buttons such as share on facebook,twitter,email,download .Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [Share Kit](http://www.getsharekit.com/).

Comment: can anyone provide me some code or some example of how to add them.

Comment: The Share Kit site has a nice tutorial on how to up and running http://www.getsharekit.com/install/#download

Comment: Hi all, I want to show buttons such as facebook button ,twitter button and all.Please help me in doing that...